# spring test without mocking

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-test

I had to develop a Service in a non Spring project, starting to use Spring dependency injection (NOT SPRING BOOT). It's a test with real data so I don't want to mock any of the services used.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {
private final Service2 service2;

public Service1(Service2 service2) {
    this.service2 = service2;
}

public X doSomething() {
    ...
}
}
```

So in order to test Service1, I created a config class

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBeansConfig {

@Bean
public Service2 service1(Service2 service2) {
    return new Service1(service2);
}

@Bean
public Service2 service2() {
    return new Service2();
}
}
```

and the following test so Service2 is not mocked.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class })
public class Service1Test {

@Autowired
public Service1 sut;

@Test
public void myTest() {
    X result = service1.soSomething();
}
}
```

But service1 is null. I'm sure I'm missing some configuration but error log is just telling me service1 is null.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Its `null` where? Also your configuration is wrong... You have 2 beans of type `Service2`. Your test method is `public` are you using the correct JUnit annotations and not mixing jUnit4 and Junit5?

Comment: Please post code that is compiling/working, your code has errors that make it difficult for others to investigate your issue. E.g. you have 2 `Service2` beans in `SpringBeansConfig` and in `Service1Test` the `@ContextConfiguration` mentions a class that does not exist `Config.class` instead of `SpringBeansConfig.class`

Comment: Do you use JUnit4 or JUnit5? (this is important because the use different annotations, and using the wrong one would lead to an problem like yours)